# Stabilize MP4 from gyroscope metadata? (Insta360)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, linux, stabilisation, action-cam

I just got an Insta360 One R 1-inch sensor and the footage is shaky as hell. I realised that you need their desktop application to actually stabilise in post-production but since I'm on Linux this is not possible.

By probing the MP4 recorded with `exiftool` it's clear that there is some metadata

```
$> exiftool -ee -G3 PRO_VID_20210312_225421_00_004.mp4
..
[Doc8914]       Accelerometer                   : -0.2275390625 -1.2587890625 -0.140380859375
[Doc8914]       Angular Velocity                : 0.0109715647995472 0.0351055897772312 0.0297343395650387
[Doc8915]       Time Code                       : 238.231
[Doc8915]       Accelerometer                   : -0.21630859375 -1.263671875 -0.13916015625
[Doc8915]       Angular Velocity                : 0.0109715647995472 0.0606719367206097 0.00416799262166023
[Doc8916]       Time Code                       : 238.233
[Doc8916]       Accelerometer                   : -0.205078125 -1.26513671875 -0.135009765625
..
```

I was wondering.. is there someway to stabilise the footage by using this metadata **on Linux**?

When we use vid.stab or similar we usually create this sort of metadata with some analysis. But since we already have this data, there must be a way we can skip that step and use it directly?